# Can't get jquery and flexslider working on a new Wordpress install

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add a simple slider to a wordpress child theme page and I can't get it to work.

Slider html(header.php):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slide'
  );

  // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
          //echo '<li><a href="#">' . the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>    </li>';//this was wrong
          echo '<li><a href="#">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>    </li>';//this is right
      }
      echo '</ul></div>';
  } else {
      // no posts found
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Scripts(functions.php)

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'slide', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/flexslider/flexscript.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

if ( is_front_page() ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
}

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

jquery.flexislider.js is the required js file.
flexiscript.js contains this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

I also have the css included in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: do u have any console errors..??

Comment: just this: `The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating` which I doubt has anything to do with the slider or jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't enqueueing your flexscript.js file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('slide');
```

Comment: hi, thank you. that actually did something. It added the controls for the slider ... but there is still something wrong. Here is a link: http://limitless.smoige.com/

Comment: i thought that `wp_register_script('jquery');` is how wordpress jquery is registered.

Comment: Yep, Missing argument 2 for wp_register_script(). You don't have to register jQuery. If jQuery is in one of the dependencies, WordPress will automatically enqueue it for you ;)

Comment: Still showing both images instead of slider. Should I register the stylesheet instead of adding it in header.php?

Comment: Looks like the slider is working, but some css styles are missing. Registering the css is preferable, but not mandatory.

Comment: Also, make sure everything inside the ul.slides element is inside a LI element. Now there are some images outside a LI element.

Comment: Wait ... I think I saw what the problem is ... for some reason the images aren't in the <li> elements. I don't think I should use `the_post_thumbnail()`

Comment: Yup ... that was it. `get_the_post_thumbnail()` did it.